# Incorrect syntax near INTO OUTFILE

Tags: sql-server

I want to output my select query result in csv file, googling for some time i found this.

```
SELECT * from appointment_master where doctorid=1266 INTO OUTFILE 'Filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I don't know what is wrong but i am getting error near 'INTO' which is `Incorrect syntax near INTO`. I am using MSSQL server 2014.

thank you.

Comment: Where in the SQL Server manual did you find that syntax?

Comment: INTO OUTFILE is from MySQL and don't work with SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

The below should work.

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'Filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM appointment_master;
```